# Converting to plane polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates

I am trying to find the periodic orbits of the following ODE:

$\ddot{x}-(1-x^{2}-\dot{x}^{2})\dot{x}+x=0$

Now in my book it says that it is easiest to see the orbits of this ODE if it is converted to polar coordinates. But if it is just a single ODE (i.e. not a system) is it still possible to create some sort of decoupled system of ODE's from this using polar coordinates?

Comment: Isn't $x$ a 2D vector ?

Comment: What is meant is to first reduce it to a first order equation in two variables, e.g. $u=x$, $v=\dot{x}$, then change to polar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply with $2\dot x$ and semi-integrate to find
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\dot x^2+x^2)=2\dot x^2(1-(\dot x^2+x^2))
$$
so it can seem as a good idea to set $r^2=\dot x^2+x^2$ and use the circle equation to define an angle $\theta$ so that
$$
\dot x=r\cosθ,~~x=r\sinθ
$$
where both $r$ and $θ$ are time-dependent functions.

Comment: Ah I see. So does that imply $\dot{r}=0$ since $\dot{x}=\dot{r}sin(\theta)+rcos({\theta})$

Comment: You missed a term, $\dot x=\dot r\sin(θ)+r\dotθ \cos(θ)$, so $\dot x(1-\dotθ)=x\frac{\dot r}{r}$. It is only for $r=1$ that you get $\dot r=0$ for the equation inquestion.